# Populating an empty array with objects

Tags: java, arrays

Im creating a Kennel, with N number of spaces (defined by the user.) and I need to populate the empty Array with N number of empty objects that can be viewed later.

here is the class to create the kennel array, Note: I have tried using an ArrayList<> of objects but wasn't able to get what I needed out of it.

```
public class Kennel {

    private Object[] kennel;
    private String type;
    private int space;
    public Kennel() {

    }
    public Kennel(String type, int space) {
        //initialize Kennel with type of animal and number of kennel spaces available.
        this.type = type;
        this.space = space;
        kennel = new Object[this.space];

    }
    //populate the kennel
    public void populateKennel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.kennel.length; ++i) {
                     //Has a constructor that sets a certain number of values in the object to empty.
            RescueAnimal animal = new RescueAnimal();
            //my attempt to add the object to the kennel
                        kennel[animal];
        }
        System.out.println(kennel);
    }

}
```

here is the toString() from the RescueAnimal class, this is the data that should be added to the array, all with "none" or "empty" values, and should later print out in this manner.

```
    public String toString() {
       // return name; type; gender; age; weight; acquisitionDate; statusDate; acquisitionSource;
        return( "Name: " + this.name + " Type: " + this.type + "\n"
              +"Gender: " + this.gender + " age: " + this.age + "\n"
              +"Weight: " + this.weight + " Day acquired: " + this.acquisitionDate + "\n"
              +"Status: " + this.statusDate + " Acquired: " + this.acquisitionSource + "\n\n");
    }
```

here in the main part of the code I attempt to call a New kennel array with the type of animal (Dog) and the amount of kennel spaces (10), as well as an attempt to populate that kennel with empty objects..

```
Kennel dogKennel = new Kennel("Dog", 10);
dogKennel.populateKennel();
```

however my attempt fails to accomplish this, I keep returning an Initialization error in the Kennel class.

do you guys have any pointers thatll help me accomplish this task?

Comment: What about doing kennel[i] = animal ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to set the member of the array

```
kennel[i] = animal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the kennel object to a Rescue Animal Array: 
`

public class Kennel {

```
private RescueAnimal[] kennel;
private String type;
private int space;

public Kennel(String type, int space) {
    //initialize Kennel with type of animal and number of kennel spaces available.
    this.type = type;
    this.space = space;
    kennel = new RescueAnimal[this.space];

}
//populate the kennel
public void populateKennel() { // would rename this to initializeKennel since the data inside is empty
    for (int i = 0; i < this.kennel.length; ++i) {
        //Has a constructor that sets a certain number of values in the object to empty.
        RescueAnimal animal = new RescueAnimal();

        kennel[i]= animal;
    }
    //System.out.println(kennel);
    //remove this, only want to print after there is data in it and you have defined a toString for Kennel
}
public String toString(){
    String s="Kennel Type: "+type + "Kennel Capacity: "+space + "animals: \n";
    for (int i =0; i < kennel.length; ++i){
        s+= kennel[i].toString()+"\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

`